# file_get_contents время ожидания соединения истекло

Tags: php

На хостинге выдает ошибку о том, что время ожидания соединения истекло, при этом сайт работает, на локальной машине также все работает

```
$json_url_server1 = "https://rust-servers.info/api/194.87.232.60_30015.json";
$json_string1 = file_get_contents($json_url_server1);
$parsed_json1 = json_decode($json_string1,true);

$players_cur1 = $parsed_json1['players_cur'];
$players_max1 = $parsed_json1['players_max'];
if($parsed_json1['online_state'] == 1){
    $online1 = 'ОНЛАЙН';
}
else{
    $online1 = 'ОФФЛАЙН';
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте курлом

Comment: на локальной машине `ip` адрес клиента и сервера одинаковый, а на хосте разный. покажите полный код и откуда вы получили эту ссылку

Comment: @webDev_ с чего вы взяли, что ссылка не статически забита?

Comment: Ссылка статическая, это старая версия API rust-servers.info, но информацию по адресу выводит

Comment: @teran предположил, что ссылка привязывается по IP адресу. Теперь же понял что нет

Comment: @pantaleone48 проблема не в коде, просто ваш хостинг не может получить ответ от сервера, так же как и я